# Convert Python sequence to NumPy array, filling missing values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sequence, variable-length-array

The implicit conversion of a Python sequence of *variable-length* lists into a NumPy array cause the array to be of type *object*.

```
v = [[1], [1, 2]]
np.array(v)
>>> array([[1], [1, 2]], dtype=object)
```

Trying to force another type will cause an exception:

```
np.array(v, dtype=np.int32)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What is the most efficient way to get a dense NumPy array of type int32, by filling the "missing" values with a given placeholder?

From my sample sequence `v`, I would like to get something like this, if 0 is the placeholder

```
array([[1, 0], [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
import itertools
np.array(list(itertools.zip_longest(*v, fillvalue=0))).T
Out: 
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 2]])
```

Note: For Python 2, it is [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: This seems really good when the the size variation is huge within the list elements based on a quick runtime test for a large dataset.

Answer (score 23):

Here's an almost* vectorized boolean-indexing based approach that I have used in several other posts -

```
def boolean_indexing(v):
    lens = np.array([len(item) for item in v])
    mask = lens[:,None] > np.arange(lens.max())
    out = np.zeros(mask.shape,dtype=int)
    out[mask] = np.concatenate(v)
    return out
```

**Sample run**

```
In [27]: v
Out[27]: [[1], [1, 2], [3, 6, 7, 8, 9], [4]]

In [28]: out
Out[28]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

*Please note that this coined as almost vectorized because the only looping performed here is at the start, where we are getting the lengths of the list elements. But that part not being so computationally demanding should have minimal effect on the total runtime.

**Runtime test**

In this section I am timing [`DataFrame-based solution by @Alberto Garcia-Raboso`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619278/3293881), [`itertools-based solution by @ayhan`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619333/3293881) as they seem to scale well and the boolean-indexing based one from this post for a relatively larger dataset with three levels of size variation across the list elements.

Case #1 : Larger size variation

```
In [44]: v = [[1], [1,2,4,8,4],[6,7,3,6,7,8,9,3,6,4,8,3,2,4,5,6,6,8,7,9,3,6,4]]

In [45]: v = v*1000

In [46]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(v).fillna(0).values.astype(np.int32)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.82 ms per loop

In [47]: %timeit np.array(list(itertools.izip_longest(*v, fillvalue=0))).T
100 loops, best of 3: 5.11 ms per loop

In [48]: %timeit boolean_indexing(v)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.88 ms per loop
```

Case #2 : Lesser size variation

```
In [49]: v = [[1], [1,2,4,8,4],[6,7,3,6,7,8]]

In [50]: v = v*1000

In [51]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(v).fillna(0).values.astype(np.int32)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.12 ms per loop

In [52]: %timeit np.array(list(itertools.izip_longest(*v, fillvalue=0))).T
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop

In [53]: %timeit boolean_indexing(v)
100 loops, best of 3: 5 ms per loop
```

Case #3 : Larger number of elements (100 max) per list element

```
In [139]: # Setup inputs
     ...: N = 10000 # Number of elems in list
     ...: maxn = 100 # Max. size of a list element
     ...: lens = np.random.randint(0,maxn,(N))
     ...: v = [list(np.random.randint(0,9,(L))) for L in lens]
     ...: 

In [140]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(v).fillna(0).values.astype(np.int32)
1 loops, best of 3: 292 ms per loop

In [141]: %timeit np.array(list(itertools.izip_longest(*v, fillvalue=0))).T
1 loops, best of 3: 264 ms per loop

In [142]: %timeit boolean_indexing(v)
10 loops, best of 3: 95.7 ms per loop
```

To me, it seems <strike>`itertools.izip_longest` is doing pretty well!</strike> there's no clear winner, but would have to be taken on a case-by-case basis!

Comment: @ayhan Hmm can't run that on my Python 2 version. Could it 
be my NumPy version 1.11.1?

Comment: I guess all methods are iterating over `v` but as the lists inside v are getting larger, your method starts to be faster. I tried it with n=10^3, m=10^4 and it was 5 times faster. I have 1.11.1 in Python 3 but results are very similar to Python 2.7 numpy 1.10.4

Comment: @ayhan Appreciate the feedback and honesty! ;) Added another case for that :)

Answer (score 17):

Pandas and its `DataFrame`-s deal beautifully with missing data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

v = [[1], [1, 2]]
print(pd.DataFrame(v).fillna(0).values.astype(np.int32))

# array([[1, 0],
#        [1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: This is great for data with less size variation, good solution really!

Answer (score 3):

```
max_len = max(len(sub_list) for sub_list in v)

result = np.array([sub_list + [0] * (max_len - len(sub_list)) for sub_list in v])

>>> result
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 2]])

>>> type(result)
numpy.ndarray
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a general way:

```
>>> v = [[1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12]]
>>> max_len = np.argmax(v)
>>> np.hstack(np.insert(v, range(1, len(v)+1),[[0]*(max_len-len(i)) for i in v])).astype('int32').reshape(len(v), max_len)
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  0,  0],
       [ 7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend the same logic to deeper levels (list of lists of lists,..) you can use tensorflow ragged tensors and convert to tensors/arrays. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
v = [[1], [1, 2]]
padded_v = tf.ragged.constant(v).to_tensor(0)
```

This creates an array padded with 0.
or a deeper example:

```
w = [[[1]], [[2],[1, 2]]]
padded_w = tf.ragged.constant(w).to_tensor(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to convert pandas dataframe first, after that convert it to numpy array

```
ll = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(ll)
print(df)
#    0  1    2    3
# 0  1  2  3.0  NaN
# 1  4  5  NaN  NaN
# 2  6  7  8.0  9.0

npl = df.to_numpy()
print(npl)

# [[ 1.  2.  3. nan]
#  [ 4.  5. nan nan]
#  [ 6.  7.  8.  9.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a numpy broadcast error with Alexander's answer so I added a small variation with [numpy.pad](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html):

```
pad = len(max(X, key=len))

result = np.array([np.pad(i, (0, pad-len(i)), 'constant') for i in X])
```