# Inserting one item on a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

How do I insert a single element into an array on numpy.  I know how to insert an entire column or row using the insert and axis parameter.  But how do I insert/expand by one.

For example, say I have an array:

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

How do I insert 0 (on the same row), say on (1, 1) location, say:

```
1 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 1
```

is this doable?  If so, then how do you do the opposite (on the same column), say:

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
  1
```

Comment: Those things you want to create don't look like matrices to me.

Comment: ok I guess you could say its arrays

Comment: What are you _trying_ to do --- as in, what's your overall objective?  Odds are, either your goal is not helped by a messy data structure like that, or it _is_ and NumPy is not the right tool for the job.  (But I'm willing to be surprised.)

Comment: You can't. Numpy arrays are not designed for those irregular sizes.  Well, maybe you could get something to work for you using arrays of type `object` (see @AmiTavory's answer), but they can introduce other problems.

Comment: I am actually using objects in the arrays.  If the array cannot be irregular, then I guess I can pad null/none on the ends to keep it as a regular size.

Comment: Here's a related one, if you are willing to pad with `None`, etc. : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/convert-python-sequence-to-numpy-array-filling-missing-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy has something that *looks* like ragged arrays, but those are arrays of objects, and probably not what you want. Note the difference in the following:

```
In [27]: np.array([[1, 2], [3]])
Out[27]: array([[1, 2], [3]], dtype=object)

In [28]: np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Out[28]:
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

If you want to insert `v` into row/column `i/j`, you can do so by padding the other rows. This is easy to do:

```
In [29]: a = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]])

In [30]: i, j, v = 1, 1, 3

In [31]: np.array([np.append(a[i_], [0]) if i_ != i else np.insert(a[i_], j, v) for i_ in range(a.shape[1])])
Out[31]:
array([[1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

To pad along columns, not rows, first transpose `a`, then perform this operation, then transpose again.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `append()` of regular Python arrays (not numpy)
Here is a short example

```
A = [[1,1,1],
     [1,1,1],
     [1,1,1]]
A[1].append(1)
```

The result is

```
[[1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1]]   # like in your example
```

Column extension with one element is impossible, because values are stored by rows. Thechnically you can do something like this `A.append([None,1,None])`, but this is bad practice.