# Convert list of lists with different lengths to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have list of lists with different lengths (e.g. `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]`) and want to convert it into a `numpy` array of integers. I understand that 'sub' arrays in `numpy` multidimensional array must be the same length. So what is the most efficient way to convert such a list as in example above into a `numpy` array like this `[[1, 2, 3, 0], [4, 5, 0, 0], [6, 7, 8, 9]]`, i.e. completed with zeros?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

you could make a numpy array with np.zeros and fill them with your list elements as shown below.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
import numpy as np
b = np.zeros([len(a),len(max(a,key = lambda x: len(x)))])
for i,j in enumerate(a):
    b[i][0:len(j)] = j
```

results in

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  0.]
 [ 4.  5.  0.  0.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.  9.]]
```

Answer (score 23):

Do some preprocessing on the list, by padding the shorter sublists, before converting to a numpy array:

```
>>> lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [1, 7, 8, 9]]
>>> pad = len(max(lst, key=len))
>>> np.array([i + [0]*(pad-len(i)) for i in lst])
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 0, 0],
       [1, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: i feel this is more pythonic than accepted answer ...

Comment: More generic solution:
`np.array([np.pad(i, ((0,pad-len(i)),(0,0))) for i in lst])`
if lst is a list of 2 dimensional arrays. Therefore, for more dimensional arrays you need to add (0,0) for every new axis.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a `@Divakar` type of answer:

```
In [945]: ll = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
In [946]: lens = [len(l) for l in ll]      # only iteration
In [947]: lens
Out[947]: [3, 2, 4]
In [948]: maxlen=max(lens)
In [949]: arr = np.zeros((len(ll),maxlen),int)
In [950]: mask = np.arange(maxlen) < np.array(lens)[:,None] # key line
In [951]: mask
Out[951]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
In [952]: arr[mask] = np.concatenate(ll)    # fast 1d assignment
In [953]: arr
Out[953]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

For large lists it has the potential of being faster.  But it's harder to understand and/or recreate.

[Convert Python sequence to NumPy array, filling missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38619143) - has a good post by Divakar.  `itertools.zip_longest` is also mentioned.  This could be cited as a duplicate.

Comment: This answer is far better than the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for multidimensional arrays