# fill missing values in 3D list with zeros to create 3D numpy array

Tags: python, python-itertools, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D list `ll` which can be of size `100 K * 10 * 3`

```
ll = [
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]], [[6, 7, 8],[12, 13, 14]], [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
]
```

I want it to be

```
ll = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10,11,12]], [[6, 7, 8],[12, 13, 14], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90], [0,0,0]]]
```

so that I can create `a1 = np.array(l1)`

`a1`

```
array([
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
[[6,7,8], [12,13,14], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]
[[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90], [0,0,0]]
])
```

I have read the following but they are for 2D, i am not able to do it for 3D.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619333/5202279

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43149308/5202279

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you be more precise? Why don't you just add the missing zeros?

Comment: Are the innermost lists also of variable length? Or do they always contain three elements?

Comment: they are coordinates so will always have 3 elements.

Comment: `ll[len(ll) - 1].append([0, 0, 0])` Do you mean something like this?

Comment: @IcesHay I think the idea is to have something more general working, i.e. when you don't know how many zeros need to be padded and where.

Comment: I have edited the Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that allocates the NumPy array up front then copies the data over. Assuming you don't actually need the expanded `ll`, this should use less memory than appending the 0-triples to `ll` before creating `a1`:

```
a1 = np.zeros((len(ll), max([len(k) for k in ll]), 3))
for ctr,k in enumerate(ll):
     a1[ctr,:len(k),:] = k

a1
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.],
        [10., 11., 12.]],

       [[ 6.,  7.,  8.],
        [12., 13., 14.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],

       [[10., 20., 30.],
        [40., 50., 60.],
        [70., 80., 90.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])
```

`max([len(k) for k in ll])` tells us the maximum number of triples in any member of `ll`. We allocate a 0-initialized NumPy array of the desired size. Then in the loop, smart indexing tells us where in `a1` to copy each member of `ll`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all elements in the list, which are also lists and get the max length. Then append zeros to every "sublist" that does not have the max length.

```
m = max([len(k) for k in ll])

for i in range(0, len(ll)):
    while len(ll[i]) < m:
        ll[i].append([0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Good method, but `max` is the name of a function in Python already, so probably best not to reuse it for a variable name. You can do something like `m = max([len(k) for k in ll])` to turn the first part of your answer into something more Pythonic

Comment: You are right. I will update my answer. Thanks for your feedback.