# convert list into list of lists: each sublist is a different length, and method of filling sublists is different

Tags: python, list

input I have:

`big_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

output I want:

`list_of_lists = [[1],[2,5][3,6,8],[4,7]]`

I have manually defined the output I need as a list-of-lists as the following:

- 1st sublist length = 1
- 2nd sublist length = 2
- 3rd sublist length = 3
- 4th sublist length = 2

So the total number of elements in the output `list_of_lists` = 1x2x3x2 = 8. The same number of elements as in the input, `big_list`.

I want to fill the sublists by first filling the 1st element of each sublist, and then the 2nd element of each sublist, etc etc, so I get this:

`list_of_lists = [[1],[2,5][3,6,8],[4,7]]`

To clarify, I know how to create a list of lists. And I've seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/convert-python-sequence-to-numpy-array-filling-missing-values) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146266/convert-list-of-lists-with-different-lengths-to-a-numpy-array).

But these answers are either about creating a list-of-lists where the sublists are of equal lengths, or they deal with sublists of different lengths by creating sublists of the largest length and filling the smaller ones with a "filler" value. Additionally, most answers create the first sublist from the first n elements, the second sublist from the second n elements, etc.

Neither of these is what I want.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the logic here?

Comment: @Guy, what do you mean?

Comment: Based on what are you dividing the values to sublists?

Comment: You fail to explain how you determine the sizes of the sublists and how they are populated. You've also failed to to show the code you've tried. Also, "and get something like this" is rather vague. What would the output be for an input list of [1,2,3,4] ?

Comment: @Codist, (1) I want to do this multiple times with different lists/lengths each time, so I'm looking for code where the sublist lengths are variables, so the sizes of the sublists doesn't matter. (2) I can change "something like this" to "this" for the sake of the question; I've explained the logic below to explain why the output list I've created looks the way it does. (3) I've tried things like in the references I've added, but they're not what I'm looking for, so I'm totally lost here and don't know where to begin. Any suggestions?

Comment: "by first filling the first element of each sublist, and then the second element of each sublist, etc etc" it is totally unclear to me the logic here. So for example, why are there 4 sublists in the resulting list?

Comment: What would the output be for an input list of [1,2,3,4] ?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The first element of the big_list(the number 1) = the first element of the first sublist. The second element of the big_list(the number 2) = the first element of the second sublist.

Comment: @abra that doesn't really clarify. Why are their 4 sublists in the resulting list? So I think I understand the pattern give that there are 4 sublists, but I dont' know why there are 4 sublists. Why not 5, or 3? Or is 4 sublists *an input*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the number & elements of each list is defined by me. Is that what you mean by input?

Comment: @abra yes. this is really a crucial piece of information. In general, you should define what are the *inputs*, in this case, it is your list and an integer, 4, which is the number of resulting sublists.

Comment: I can see the logic for the input and output in the question and I have code that will process that but it's not generic. That's why we need to know the output for different input sizes - e.g., [1,2,3,4]. The number of sub-lists cannot be arbitrarily assigned as there will be a dependency on the size of the input list

Comment: Why is 5 in the second sublist?

Comment: @Codist the elements of the big_list matches the number of elements in list_of_lists; the aim is to divide the big_list elements into the list_of_lists; where I define the number of sublists and the number of elements in each of these sublists.

Comment: @Codist the number of sublists/ elements in each sublist is defined by me, so the size of the input list will always be equal to the size of the output

Comment: @9769953 please see the logic explained just beneath the output

Comment: No, that doesn't explain it. It explains the first item of each sublist, not the second or third items; nor why the first sublist has only 1 item (note that it says "and then the second element of *each* sublist", but there is no second element in the first sublist, so that statement doesn't match up with the result). I can come up with some logic to explain it, but then I'm second-guessing.

Comment: You should also edit your question to include the fact that you decide on the number of sublists (as per one of your comments), and what, in this example, that number of sublists is.

Comment: wait wait wait. You know the lenghts of each sublist *ahead of time*? It could conceivably be 3, 1, 2, 2 ?

Comment: @Codist No need to be snarky. I asked because it's something I'm trying to do, and I figured more experienced people might think of something I didn't.

Comment: The one thing that is technically still missing in your question, is the fact that you step through the items of the original list *in order*, and step through the sublist *in order*, adding one item each step unless they're full. It might be self-evident, but I think it's a clarification that needs to be added. "etc etc" doesn't really do that. Otherwise, it's easy to pick *random* items from the original list and follow your recipe to fill the sublist, which results in different output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the size of each sublist in a list. Assert that the sum of the sublist sizes is equal to the size of the input list.

This will be inefficient for large input lists.

```
big_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
sublists = [1,2,3,2]
assert sum(sublists) == len(big_list)
lol = [[] for _ in sublists]

i = -1

for v in big_list:
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i == len(lol):
            i = 0
        if len(lol[i]) < sublists[i]:
            lol[i].append(v)
            break
        
print(lol)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [2, 5], [3, 6, 8], [4, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks. What does (i := i + 1) do? if i=-1, then doesn't -1+1 always become 0?

Comment: It's an assignment expression (a.k.a. walrus operator). The variable *i* will be incremented by one each time through the loop. So, yes, first time through it will become zero. I'll simplify the code to make it clearer