# How to convert list of arrays of different length into arrays of same lenth in python

Tags: python, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTapY.png)

to be like that :
[[1,0,0,0,0],[0.57735027, 0.57735027, 0.57735027,0,0],[0.57735027, 0.57735027, 0.57735027,0,0],and so on]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Add the actual list you are starting with as text and use the `<>` button in the editor to format it as code.

Comment: This question's title is a bit misleading,maby you should say:

"How to convert list of different length of arrays into arrays of same lenth in python"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Python sequence to NumPy array, filling missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/convert-python-sequence-to-numpy-array-filling-missing-values)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you're looking for something like:

```
data = [[1],[0.52, 0.53, 0.54],[],[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]]
max_size = 0

# identify the maximum length, for any of the lists in data
for arr in data:
    max_size = max(max_size, len(arr))

# extend each lists as required
for arr in data:
    # NOTE: the following should work, since the (max_size >= len(arr)) condition will always hold in this case
    arr.extend([0] * (max_size - len(arr)))

print(data)
```

NOTE: there will be better approaches as well. But, this might give you a direction.

Answer (score -1):

You could try doing something like this:

```py
yourArray =  [[1,0,0,0,0],[0.57735027, 0.57735027, 0.57735027,0,0],[0.57735027, 0.57735027, 0.57735027,0,0],and so on]

outputArray = []

for subArr in yourArray:
    [outputArray.append(i) for i in subArr]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
master_array = []

for a in yourArray:
   master_array.extend(a)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it was flagged for review.  Answers with no explanation are often considered low-quality. Please provide some commentary for why this is the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this(assuming it's called lists):

```
mxlen=max(len(i) for i in lists)
for i in lists:
    i.extend([0]*(mxlen-len(i)))
```