# NumPy array from list of lists with different length (padding)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list like this:

```py
lista=[[1,2,3],
       [1,2,3,4,5,6],
       [1,2],]
```

I want to get numpy.array like this, (the shorter list element be expand to the max legnth, then set tail values as zeros):

```py
array([[1,2,3,0,0,0],
       [1,2,3,4,5,6],
       [1,2,0,0,0,0],])
```

how to do? where there are some built-in methods in numpy?

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct way using numpy, since each inner list has a different amount of elements. One way could be to use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) with a `fillvalue`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

np.array(list(zip_longest(*lista, fillvalue=0))).T
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: See the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/convert-python-sequence-to-numpy-array-filling-missing-values for more details. The above scales well when there's large variation in list sizes, while boolean indexing works well for large numbers of elements.

Comment: It can also be uptimized (25% for large lists) using `np.fromiter`. `np.array(list(<iterator>))` is not the fastest choice usually.

Comment: Yes @mathfux gave it a try, but if I remember correctly np.fromiter wants a structured. Sepcifying directly a single dtype for an values yields an error

Comment: @yatu I did it this way: `dt = np.dtype([('', np.int)]*M) #or np.dtype(','.join('i'*M))`; `indices = np.fromiter(zip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=0), dt)`; `indices = indices.view(np.int).reshape(-1, M).T` where `M` is length of row (look at Robo's answer).

Comment: Gets slightly more complex for a milt improvement. But its nice to know about an alternative, thanks @mathfux :)

Answer (score -1):

How about you create a zeros numpy array and then fill the values accordingly?

```
lists = [[1,2,3],
       [1,2,3,4,5,6],
       [1,2]]

a = np.zeros([len(lists), max([len(x) for x in lists])])

for i, sub in enumerate(lists):
    a[i][0:len(sub)] = sub
```