# How to pad a tensor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

How would I pad this tensor by adding element 100 on the end

```
a = tensor([[ 101,  103],
    [ 101, 1045, 223],
    [ 101,  777, 665 , 889],
    [ 101,  888]])
```

So the result would be:

```
 b = tensor([[ 101,  103, 100, 100],
    [ 101, 1045, 223, 100],
    [ 101,  777, 665 , 889],
    [ 101,  888, 100, 100]])
```

I know the functions is torch.nn.functional.pad(), but i could not any simple example with a tensor like this that is probably a 2d tensor.

Which was surprising, because this is what a (most) typical padding is.

Comment: There is the same problem using `numpy` answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63879852/18205911

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the `numpy` case, see [Convert Python sequence to NumPy array, filling missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619143/convert-python-sequence-to-numpy-array-filling-missing-values), you could adjust the size of your sub lists using `itertools.zip_longest`.

```py
from itertools import zip_longest
tensor_lists = [
    [ 101,  103],
    [ 101, 1045, 223],
    [ 101,  777, 665 , 889],
    [ 101,  888]
]
fillvalue = 100
padded_list = list(zip(*zip_longest(*tensor_lists, fillvalue=fillvalue)))
...  # convert to tensor and use it
```

Here, `zip_longest` adds the missing value, and the second `zip` transposes the result again. You could of cause first create the tensor and then transpose.

Comment: depending on tensor does not work. I tried something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `torch.nested.to_padded_tensor` ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nested.html)):

```py
import torch
a = [
    [101, 103],
    [101, 1045, 223],
    [101, 777, 665, 889],
    [101, 888]
]

a = torch.nested.nested_tensor(list(map(torch.tensor, a)))

torch.nested.to_padded_tensor(a, 100)
tensor([[ 101,  103,  100,  100],
        [ 101, 1045,  223,  100],
        [ 101,  777,  665,  889],
        [ 101,  888,  100,  100]])
```