# Concatenate many nd-arrays of different shapes (filling values until the edges)

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, performance

I have a list of 2d arrays of different shapes: `lst` (see the example below).

I would like to concatenate them into a 3d array of shape `(len(lst), maxx, maxy)`, where `maxx` is the maximum `.shape[0]` of all arrays, and `maxy` is the maximum `.shape[1]`.

If an array's shape is smaller than `(maxx, maxy)`, then this array should start at the top left corner, and all the missing values should be filled with some value of choice (e.g. 0 or `np.nan`).

##### Example:

```py
lst = [np.array([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4]]),
       np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6]]),
       np.array([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4],
                 [5, 6]])]

# maxx == 3
# maxy == 3

result = np.array([[[1, 2, 0],
                    [3, 4, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]],

                    [[1, 2, 3],
                     [4, 5, 6],
                     [0, 0, 0]],

                    [[1, 2, 0],
                     [3, 4, 0],
                     [5, 6, 0]]])
```

**Notes:**

[`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)
requires the shapes of all arrays to match.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38619143/14627505) is similar - but it is only for 1d arrays.

---

#### A sub-problem:

As a special case, you may assume that `.shape[1] == maxy` is the same for all arrays. For example:

```py
lst = [np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6]]),
       np.array([[1, 2, 3]]),
       np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6]
                 [7, 8, 9]])]
```

---

##### Bonus (a hard question):

Can this be applied to more dimensions? E.g., while concatenating 3d arrays into a 4d array, all 3d arrays (rectangular parallelepipeds) will start at the same *corner*, and if their shapes are too small - the missing values (until the edges) will be filled with 0 or `np.nan`.

---

How to do this at all? How to do this efficiently (potentially for thousands of arrays, each with thousands of elements)?

- Maybe creating an array of the final shape and filling it somehow in a vectored way?
- Or converting all arrays into dataframes and concatenating them with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)?
- Maybe SciPy has some helpful functions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution for general dimensions, non-vectorized but avoiding a slow `np.pad` call. (~20x faster, benchmarked with the example *lst* * 10000).

```py
import numpy as np

def fill_axis(lst):
    shapes = np.array([arr.shape for arr in lst])
    res = np.zeros((len(shapes),) + (*shapes.max(0),), int)
    for x, arr in enumerate(lst):
        slices = [x]
        slices += (slice(None, shape) for shape in arr.shape)
        res[tuple(slices)] = arr
    return res

lst = lst * 10000

%timeit fill_axis(lst)
# 77.3 ms ± 2.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# solution by @TimRoberts https://stackoverflow.com/a/73536898/14277722
def pad_fill(lst):
    maxx = max(x.shape[0] for x in lst)
    maxy = max(x.shape[1] for x in lst)

    res = [np.pad( k, [(0,maxx-k.shape[0]),(0,maxy-k.shape[1])] ) for k in lst]
    return np.array(res)

%timeit pad_fill(lst)
# 1.82 s ± 82.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

np.testing.assert_equal(pad_fill(lst), fill_axis(lst))
```

An example with stacked 3D arrays

```py
lst_4D = [np.arange(1*2*3*3).reshape(1,2,3,3),
          np.arange(2*3*2*2).reshape(2,3,2,2)]

fill_axis(lst_4D)
```

Output

```
array([[[[[ 0,  1,  2],
          [ 3,  4,  5],
          [ 6,  7,  8]],

         [[ 9, 10, 11],
          [12, 13, 14],
          [15, 16, 17]],

         [[ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]]],


        [[[ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]],

         [[ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]],

         [[ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]]]],



       [[[[ 0,  1,  0],
          [ 2,  3,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]],

         [[ 4,  5,  0],
          [ 6,  7,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]],

         [[ 8,  9,  0],
          [10, 11,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]]],


        [[[12, 13,  0],
          [14, 15,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]],

         [[16, 17,  0],
          [18, 19,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]],

         [[20, 21,  0],
          [22, 23,  0],
          [ 0,  0,  0]]]]])
```

An adaptation of [@divakar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619350/14277722) for 2D arrays. ~2x faster with larger lists than the more general solution in my benchmarks, but harder to generalize to more dimensions.

```py
def einsum_fill(lst):
    shapes = np.array([arr.shape for arr in lst])
    a = np.arange(shapes[:,0].max()) < shapes[:,[0]]
    b = np.arange(shapes[:,1].max()) < shapes[:,[1]]
    mask = np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', a, b)
    res = np.zeros_like(mask, int)
    res[mask] = np.concatenate([arr.ravel() for arr in lst])
    return res
                 
%timeit einsum_fill(lst)
# 46.7 ms ± 1.26 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

np.testing.assert_equal(einsum_fill(lst), fill_axis(lst))
```

Comment: Thanks! Your function `fill_axis` _just works_ correctly if you simply pass the arrays that have more dimensions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy.pad to do this.

```
import numpy as np

lst = [np.array([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4]]),
       np.array([[1, 2, 3],
                 [4, 5, 6]]),
       np.array([[1, 2],
                 [3, 4],
                 [5, 6]])]

maxx = max(x.shape[0] for x in lst)
maxy = max(x.shape[1] for x in lst)

lst = [np.pad( k, [(0,maxx-k.shape[0]),(0,maxy-k.shape[1])] ) for k in lst]
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[array([[1, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
 array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0]]),
 array([[1, 2, 0],
       [3, 4, 0],
       [5, 6, 0]])]
```

This process will work with any number of dimensions.  You'd have to use a loop instead of the `maxx`/`maxy` computation.

Comment: Thanks. `numpy.pad` is a very useful function here. And I can convert this output to a numpy array easily. But I am still interested to see the comparison of different methods in terms of speed on large arrays

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be ran in `44 ms` for example with `lst * 10000`:

```
def new_(lst):

    maxx = max(x.shape[0] for x in lst)
    maxy = max(x.shape[1] for x in lst)

    arr = np.zeros((len(lst), maxx, maxy))
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        arr[i, :lst[i].shape[0], :lst[i].shape[1]] = lst[i]
    return arr
```

Which can be accelerated by numba as:

```
lst_nb = nb.typed.List(lst)

@nb.njit(nb.float64[:, :, :](nb.types.ListType(nb.int_[:, ::1])))
def numba_(lst):

    maxx = 0
    maxy = 0
    for x in lst:
        maxx = max(x.shape[0], maxx)
        maxy = max(x.shape[1], maxy)

    arr = np.zeros((len(lst), maxx, maxy))
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        arr[i, :lst[i].shape[0], :lst[i].shape[1]] = lst[i]
    return arr
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for 2d arrays, and if you replace the way you calculate `maxx` and `maxy` to the way like TimRoberts does: `maxx = max(x.shape[0] for x in lst)`, then your function is as fast as `einsum_fill`

Comment: @VladimirFokow, I didn't check that and don't know the reason. However, its performance is near `einsum_fill`. I think this function could be faster more, but I am busy for a day; I will come back and check.

Comment: I think the reason is that the list comprehension is faster than a for-loop

Comment: @VladimirFokow, you are right, using it make it faster even than `einsum_fill` e.g. if `lst = lst * 50000`. However, I will try to improve more if I could.

Comment: Okay! Is the fully vectorized solution even possible? (without **any** for loops and comprehensions)

Comment: I don't know and I don't think so.

Comment: @VladimirFokow I have added a numba version with a little inquiry, you can test it.

Comment: @VladimirFokow, It seems numba is much faster (>10 times) than the previous code.  I didn't consider `lst_nb = nb.typed.List(lst)` in timings before, and it was at least 20 to 30 times faster as I remember. Please, send me the feedback if you test its performance.