# Finding the largest time gap in a list of years

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe (around 100 million rows) in the following manner:

```
ID   Years
1    [1990,1991,1995,2000,2001,2006]
2    [1990,1990]
3    [1980,1981,1990,1995]
```

I want it to return the first occurrence of *the largest gap between two consecutive years* as the following dataframe (you can assume that the lists of years are sorted in order):

```
ID    largest_gap   from_year  to_year
1     5             1995       2000
2     0             1990       1990
3     9             1981       1990
```

Any idea of the most efficient way to calculate this?

Comment: What if the number of years is less than two? What if there are multiple instances of `largest_gap`s - Do you want the first one or the last, or any is fine?

Comment: No case of less than two and I want the first instance of the largest gap. These are easy to do once fixed though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution, which is based on [`numpy.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html):

```
def get_years(x):
    a = np.array(x)
    idx = (a - np.roll(a, 1))[1:].argmax()
    return a[[idx, idx+1]]

df[['from_year', 'to_year']] = pd.DataFrame(df['Years'].map(get_years).tolist())
```

Output:

```
   ID                                 Years  from_year  to_year
0   1  [1990, 1991, 1995, 2000, 2001, 2006]       1995     2000
1   2                          [1990, 1990]       1990     1990
2   3              [1980, 1981, 1990, 1995]       1981     1990
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the largest gap within each list, the best is to loop. Here using [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise):

```
from itertools import pairwise

df['largest_gap'] = [max(b-a for a,b in pairwise(l)) for l in df['Years']]
```

Or with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
import numpy as np

df['largest_gap'] = [np.diff(l).max() for l in df['Years']]
```

Output:

```
   ID                                 Years  largest_gap
0   1  [1990, 1991, 1995, 2000, 2001, 2006]            5
1   2                          [1990, 1990]            0
2   3              [1980, 1981, 1990, 1995]            9
```

For a full newt DataFrame:

```
def max_gap(l):
    d = np.diff(l)
    i = d.argmax()
    return pd.Series({'largest_gap': d[i],
                      'from_year': l[i],
                      'to_year': l[i+1]})

out = df[['ID']].join(df['Years'].apply(max_gap))
```

Or for more recent pandas versions:

```
def max_gap(l):
    d = np.diff(l)
    i = d.argmax()
    return {'largest_gap': d[i],
            'from_year': l[i],
            'to_year': l[i+1]}

out = df[['ID']].join(pd.DataFrame([max_gap(x) for x in df['Years']]))
```

Output:

```
   ID  largest_gap  from_year  to_year
0   1            5       1995     2000
1   2            0       1990     1990
2   3            9       1981     1990
```

Comment: @Mark given the original question, you had a nice approach, you deleted when I was about to upvote it ;)

Comment: 1981 should be the `from_year` in `ID==3`, not 1980.  It's the min year of the largest gap, not of the entire list.

Comment: @eduffy I had missed that, thanks I'll fix it

Answer (score 2):

To get `from_year`, `to_year`, and `largest_gap`, you can do something like the following.

```py
from itertools import pairwise

def get_max_gap(years):
    if len(years) < 2:
        return -1, -1, -1

    max_gap = (years[0], years[1])
    for start, end in pairwise(years):
        max_gap = max(max_gap, (start, end), key=lambda x: x[1] - x[0])

    start, end = max_gap
    return start, end, end - start


df["from_year"], df["to_year"], df["largest_gap"] = zip(*df["Years"].apply(get_max_gap))
```

This function returns `-1` for all new columns if the length of years is insufficient. Also, it returns the last match for `largest_gap` - in case there are multiple largest gaps, it returns the last one.

Since you have a lot of rows, you might want to apply a `tqdm` wrapper around pandas, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import pairwise
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

... logic as before


df["from_year"], df["to_year"], df["largest_gap"] = zip(
    *df["Years"].progress_apply(get_max_gap)
)
```

Essentially, you replace the `df.apply` with `df.progress_apply` to get the progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive solution:

```
df['largest_gap'] = df['Years'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).diff().max())
```

Output:

```
   ID                                 Years  largest_gap
0   1  [1990, 1991, 1995, 2000, 2001, 2006]          5.0
1   2                          [1990, 1990]          0.0
2   3              [1980, 1981, 1990, 1995]          9.0
```

Comment: Hi this isn't what I meant. I want the largest gap between two consecutive years, not the difference between the max and min. The answer dataframe is what the output should produce based on the example I provided. I further clarified the question. Sorry for the misinterpretation.

Comment: @BKS I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is huge, you can use `numpy`:

```
# Create a full array to store years*
lgth = df['Years'].str.len().to_numpy()
m, n = len(lgth), max(lgth)
rm, rn = np.arange(m), np.arange(n)

arr = np.zeros((m, n), dtype=np.int16)
msk = rn < lgth[:, None]
arr[msk] = np.concatenate(df['Years'])

# Compute the gap
gap = np.diff(arr, axis=1)
idx = np.argmax(gap, axis=1)

# Final dataframe
out = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': df['ID'],
    'largest_gap': gap[rm, idx],
    'from_year': arr[rm, idx],
    'to_year': arr[rm, idx+1],
}, index=df.index)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   ID  largest_gap  from_year  to_year
0   1            5       1995     2000
1   2            0       1990     1990
2   3            9       1981     1990

>>> arr
array([[1990, 1991, 1995, 2000, 2001, 2006],
       [1990, 1990,    0,    0,    0,    0],
       [1980, 1981, 1990, 1995,    0,    0]], dtype=int16)

>>> gap
array([[    1,     4,     5,     1,     5],
       [    0, -1990,     0,     0,     0],
       [    1,     9,     5, -1995,     0]], dtype=int16)
```

*Adapted from [@divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38619350/15239951)